# Cannot display js script in ie using querySelectorAll in XMLdom

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So I have been searching everywhere, tried everything, but still, my script doesn't display in IE!! Any version! It displays in FF and Chrome beautifully, but ie, AAAAAARGH!! I changed the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag to my head, checked that my browser wasn't in quirks mode, or compat mode and just running in standards mode, deleted my cookies, history and reset my ie settings, checked my security settings and still nothing! What else am I missing? I am looking for that "missing link" that will FINALLY display my script in ie. Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated.
SITUATION: I am using an html template to display and XML file using js.

JS:

```
var xmlhttp, xmlDoc, y
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)  
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/localfile/xmlfilename.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();

var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var y = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll(".class1, .class2");    

document.write("<ul id='feed' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>");
for (i=0;i<y.length;i++)
  {     
    document.write("<li><strong>"+y[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</strong><br>"+y[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"<br>"+y[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</li>");
  }
document.write("</ul>");
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">

  <channel>

    <item class="class1">
    <title>Update's Title</title>
    <pubDate>28 Oct 2015</pubDate>
    <description><![CDATA[Whatever the update is with some <a href="/link/file.htm">links</a>.]]></description>
    </item>

    <item class="class2">
      <title>Another Update Title</title>
      <pubDate>1 Oct 2015</pubDate>            
      <description><![CDATA[Some more <a href="/link/file2.htm#anchor">html tags</a> in the !cdata.]]></description>
    </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

Like I said, I am using an html template and using js to render my XML data. It displays very nicely in Chrome and FF, but not in ie 5+ or edge. The beauty of it all is that I don't get any errors in either browser, except for the `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/` in both FF and Chrome, and get no errors in ie. I know JQuery has some cool methods, but would rather stick with js to display my content. Sorry for the frustration, but WTH am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY FOUND THE ANSWER!! My ajax works well when I loaded the entire xml document. However, when I added the parameters to filter and only display xml nodes with the specific classes instead of the entire document, `getElementsbyClassName` and `querySelectorAll` were not working in ie and later read that neither was supported by ie n-e version: http://help.dottoro.com/ljbcjfot.php. I researched for a long time trying out new solutions, and everything in js. I took your advice to use jquery to upload my doc and began using the parameters & methods to only display the nodes with specific classes, and it was cross browser compatible. In case anyone needs it:

jquery code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
        <body>
        <ul id="feed"></ul>
        <script>
        $.ajax({
            type:       'GET',
            url:        '/file/rssfeed.xml',
            dataType:   'xml',
            success:    function(xml){
                $(xml).find("item.class1, item.class2").each(function(){            
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var date = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                $('#feed').append('<li><strong>'+title+'</strong><br>'+date+'<br>'+description+'</li>');            
                });     
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

I added a `ul` tag in the html with the `id="feed"` and the `li`s fell in place for each post. Originally, I used the js to upload the xml document and display all the nodes in the html template, but had to use jquery to filter and display only the xml nodes with separate classes (`item.class1, item.class2`). The original js/ajax script, without the parameters, is cross browser compatible, and the jquery script I'm using now, filters and displays in Chrome, FF & IE!! Yay!! Take that ie!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to do the ajax stuff using jQuery.
If it works, you will know that the problem is the ajax code ...

Answer (score 0):

After rechecking my ajax, I was searching for an alternative method for both getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll, when I read an article about the XMLDocument Object: http://help.dottoro.com/ljbcjfot.php & read that neither was supported by ie. Ugh, gonna have to rewrite the script all over again, for the 3rd time, but using jQuery. It makes sense that ie's error console kept telling me that querySelectorAll method was not supported. *rolling eyes* Thanks for the help Guilherme.